# How can I bind Dictionary to a partial view in ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor template engine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following presentation class

```
public class CustomerReportPresentation
{
    public ReportFormat ReportFormat { get; set; }

    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> Data { get; set; }
}
```

In a controller I have the following code

```
CustomerReportPresentation customerReport = new CustomerReportPresentation();

customerReport.Data = ReportModel.Get(); // This will return a list like this List<Dictionary<string, object>>

customerReport.ReportFormat = ReportFormat.Tabular;

return View(customerReport);
```

Now, in my corresponding view I have the following code

```
@model Project1.Areas.Test.Presentation.CustomerReportPresentation
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@if (Model.ReportFormat == Project1.Support.ReportsGenerator.Report.Contracts.ReportFormat.Summary)
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Support/ReportsGenerator/Views/Summary.cshtml", Model.Data)
}
else
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Support/ReportsGenerator/Views/Tabular.cshtml", Model.Data)
}
```

I am passing the list to the partial view. Then each partial view will display the data differently.

Here is my partial view

```
@model List<Dictionary<string, Object>>

<ul>
    @foreach (var attributes in Model.Data)
    {
        <li>
            @foreach (var attribute in attributes)
            {
                @attribute.Value; <text>   </text>

            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

But when I run my project I get this error

```
 Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You send `Model.Data` into the partial and then try to access `Model.Data` in the partial. Remove the `Data` from the last `Model`. Strange that intellisense did not warn you that `Model.Data` don't exist in `List<Dictionary<string, Object>>`

```
@model List<Dictionary<string, Object>>

<ul>
@foreach (var attributes in Model)
{
    <li>
        @foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            @attribute.Value; <text>   </text>

        }
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Meaning the model you send from the view, that is received on the partial is not `CustomerReportPresentation` but the parameter `Data` of the `Model`

```
// At the end you sendt Model.Data, that means the Data object is recieved by the Partial
@Html.Partial("~/Support/ReportsGenerator/Views/Summary.cshtml", Model.Data)
```

Comment: Although you are right that need to be fixed, the issue still exists. It may be because I am putting the views in a custom folder.